# MSBuild : Unrecognized Publish Profile Visual Studio 2017

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to publish a project with the command line msbuild. My project is a Web Application and I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.2 (26430.13) Release . Here's my command :

---

`msbuild C:\Test\MyProject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="Debug - PUBLISH PROFILE"`

---

I've set my profile with a Platform and a Target Location, but when I execute the command, here's the returned output :

---

> The OutputPath property is not set for project 'MyProject.csproj'.  Please check to make sure
>   that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Pl
>   atform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and
>   have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

---

> No destination specified for Copy. Please supply either "DestinationFiles" or "Destination Folder".

---

> The "FindUnderPath" task was not given a value for the required parameter "Path".

---

It seems that my profile is getting unrecognized, so it takes the default value.
Someone know why ? Thx.

Comment: Is this profile really in `Properties\PublishProfiles\Debug - PUBLISH PROFILE.pubxml`? Also which version of msbuild / visual studio do you use to publish this project? what type of project is it?

Comment: Yes, it is and I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: It is a web Application.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET core application? If so, just providing the publishProfile should be sufficient. If a publishprofile is not specified, then default file system profile is used - https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/dev/src/Publish/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Targets/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.targets#L47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with this command line :

---

```
bat "msbuild \"C:\\Test\\MyProject.csproj\" /P:DeployOnBuild=true /P:PublishProfile=\"Debug - PUBLISH PROFILE"\ /P:PublishProfileRootFolder=\"C:\\Test\\Properties\\PublishProfiles\" /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /P:Platform=x86 /P:Configuration=\"Debug - CONFIGURATION PROFILE"\ "
```

---

Thx !